# Hibernate wild card

Tags: hibernate

Hie everyone.

I am still struggling with this query since yesterday  .  I have a table Author and would like jsp search  text box  to return  author names under column "name" when the user has keyed in a specific letter. Passing a string ,example (key in A will return Alice ,Z will return Zara ,P will return Peter ,R will return Remmy etc. . Since yesterday I have used Google ,Jboss,Hibernate,Stack-overflow and many other knowledge base sites   . My Attempts so far

```
@Transactional
public List<Author> getauthor() {           
   Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();       
   String searchString="A%";
   Query<Author> query = session.createQuery(
           "select a " +
           "from Author  a " +
           "where a.name like :searchString", Author.class );
   query.setParameter("searchString",searchString+"%");    
   List<Author>author =query.getResultList();    
                return author;
}


@RequestMapping("/processForm")
```

public String fetchAuthors(Model thModel) {

```
List<Author>author=authorDao.getauthor();

thModel.addAttribute("author", author);

 return "results";
```

}

Comment: What does "I'm struggling" mean precisely? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Why do you use A%% as your parameter value instead of simply A%? Also, why don't you respect the Java naming conventions, and why do you name your variable/method author/getauthor instead of authors/searchAuthors: there are several of them in a list, so it should be in plural form. Making code readable is important.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations @JBNizet. I want to search the column 'Name" for specific name . Example ,if letter "J" is key in . The results will retrieve John Grisham and other Js.  Since yesterday I have failed to overcome this obstacle . I am using A% as illustrated in my code. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I understand that. But it doesn't answer my question. What do you expect to happen, and **what happens instead**? Also, searchString is "A%", and you pass searchString + "%" as argument. So you pass "A%%".

Comment: My first attempt was just a wild card , Like 'J%' . The results displayed  were all names. Then I decided to improve using A%  and Wild-fly displayed the following error .   " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: name of: entity.Author [select a from entity.Author a where a.name like :searchString]"

Comment: I then used A%% and still getting "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: name of: entity.Author [select a from entity.Author a where a.name like :searchString]" .Error.

Comment: So you get an exception? Post the exception stack trace in the question. That's crucial information. The exception says: "could not resolve property: name of: entity.Author". So there is no name property in Author. Post the code of that entity. That's also crucial information.

Comment: Many thanks . Will do right away .